# how to set a cookie in +page.server.js and access it in +server.js

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, svelte, sveltekit, pocketbase

im having a problem with the issue above. i am trying to use google oauth to authenticate, but i get stumped with that the "expected state and verifier" dont match the "returned state and verifier from google.". the problem is before sending the request to google provider redirect i set the sate and verifier to cookies. this is done from /signup/+page.server.js the i try to access is from /api/oauth/google/+server.js and i get that the state and verifier are undefined

#### my +page.server.js action:

```js
oauth2google: async (event) => {
        const authMethods = await event.locals.pb?.collection('users_valiantlynx').listAuthMethods(); // generates a state and a verifier
        if (!authMethods) {
            return {
                authProviders: ''
            };
        }
    
        const redirectUrl = `${event.url.origin}/api/oauth/google`;
        const googleAuthProvider = authMethods.authProviders.find((provider) => provider.name === 'google');
        const authProviderRedirect = `${googleAuthProvider?.authUrl}${redirectUrl}`;
        console.log('googleAuthProvider', event);
        // Save the state and verifier in a cookie
        const state = googleAuthProvider.state;
        const verifier = googleAuthProvider.codeVerifier;

        console.log('state', state);
        console.log('verifier', verifier);

        event.cookies.set('googleAuthState', state);
        event.cookies.set('googleAuthVerifier', verifier);
        
        
        throw redirect(302, authProviderRedirect);
    }
```

#### in my +server.js i do something like:

```js
export const GET = async ({ locals, url, cookies }) => {
    console.log('GET', cookies.getAll());
    const redirectUrl = `${url.origin}/api/oauth/google`;
    const expectedState = cookies.get('googleAuthState');
    const expectedVerifier = cookies.get('googleAuthVerifier'); //! everytime the listAuthMethods is called, the verifier changes. so we cant get the verifier pocketbase function hook. cause it will be different from the one we saved in the cookie from the action hook

    console.log('expectedState', expectedState);
    console.log('expectedVerifier', expectedVerifier);

    const state = url.searchParams.get('state');
    const code = url.searchParams.get('code');

    console.log('state', state);
    console.log('code', code);



..........
```

i get this error:

expectedState undefined

expectedVerifier undefined

state e2LyMU4i1lTSGbBEDyWuBKnp8F3zJG

code 4/0AfJohXke3dhNwRBhew7jMA1_Aj5KuxuiitAeVh4Vn6g7oZy6V5DR9f8PqxM-llh8_fVs8g

state mismatch undefined e2LyMU4i1lTSGbBEDyWuBKnp8F3zJG

ive tried setting the state to the *event.locals.state* and *event.locals.verifier* intead of a cookie but it was still the same issue. when i got to +server.js i chect the event.locals and it was **undefined**.

im expecting to get the verifier and the state from my +page.server.js to my +server.js at all. then i can consider how to do it safely. preferably both

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a handle hook running that overrides the cookies.
For example, if you have something like this in your hooks.server.js:

```
response.headers.set('set-cookie', cookie);
```

it will override the cookies set in +page.server.js

Instead you can use `headers.append` to append the cookies:

```
response.headers.append('set-cookie', cookie);
```